# Background Task is not registered and the code is not working when the application is in background

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm using parse for sending push notification and its working perfectly but, in the background i.e., when the application is not running then the code for registering the background service is executed but, no task is set and the background task is not executed after receiving the notification. Please help!!

Here is the code for registering the background task

```
Debug.WriteLine("Registering task");
                var taskRegistered = false;
                var exampleTaskName = "BackgroundTask";

                foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
                {
                    if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
                    {
                        taskRegistered = true;
                        task.Value.Unregister(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
                if (!taskRegistered)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Registering task inside");
                    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                    builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
                    builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.BackgroundTask";
                    builder.Name = "PushNotification";
                    builder.SetTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.PushNotificationTrigger());
                    BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
                    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();                        
                }
```

Code that is executed in the background:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("1");
        BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        RawNotification notification = (RawNotification)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
        string content = notification.Content; 
        Debug.WriteLine("2");
        _deferral.Complete();

    }
```

Comment: Have you added your Background Task Class in Manifest File??

Comment: yes I've added the background task class in manifest file.